# setTimeout() repeatedly calling function while ignoring interval

Tags: javascript, node.js

Last time did a complete moron mistake , so double checked this time. Here is the code snippet:

```
var os = require('os');

var hostName = os.hostname();
var hostPlatform = os.platform();
var hostArch = os.arch();
var hostRelease = os.release();

function collectNow(){
    var hostInfo = {
        name : hostName,
        platform : hostPlatform,
        arch : hostArch,
        release : hostRelease,
        hostUptime : os.uptime(),
        hostTotalMem : os.totalmem(),
        hostFreeMem : os.freemem()
    };
    return hostInfo;
}


function monConnect(delay){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collectNow()));
    console.log(delay); // printing output making sure it is 10000
    setTimeout(monConnect,delay);
}

monConnect(10000);
```

This code waits about 10 secs after 1st print , then keeps printing above json in infinite loop without waiting and value of delay is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
setTimeout(monConnect,delay);
```

`monConnect` will be invoked after `delay` milliseconds. But, since `monConnect` is not passed any value, it will have the `delay` as `undefined` (the default value).

To fix this, you can pass the actual arguments to the function passed to [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg), like this

```
setTimeout(monConnect, delay, delay);
```

Now, the second argument passed to `setTimeout` will be the actual time delay after which `monConnect` should be called. The third argument is the argument passed to `monConnect` when it is invoked after the timeout.

Answer (score 3):

`delay` isn't being passed when you call `monConnect` for the second time. You need:

```
setTimeout(function () { monConnect(delay); }, delay);
```

Note that for the purpose of running a function every `delay` milliseconds, you can use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(fn, delay);
```

There is a subtle difference in that this may fail if `fn` takes more than `delay` milliseconds to run, but your function shouldn't take that long to run.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix this one call:

```
setTimeout(monConnect(delay), delay);
```